# jsf2/primefaces5 in eclipse ID with glassfish server

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

I try to use primefaces in a Java EE project. I add the jar of this library to my web-inf>lib and integrate code in web.xml but when I run the project all the balise p: are not showen O.o

this code is taken from the showcases of primefaces5

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="fr"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<h:head>
    <title>Primefaces</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
    <p:outputLabel for="basic" value="Basic:" />
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="basic" value="#{checkboxView.selectedConsoles}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS+" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U" itemValue="Wii U" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>

    <h:outputText value="Grid:" />
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="grid" value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities}" layout="grid" columns="3">
        <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-check" />

<p:dialog header="Values" modal="true" showEffect="clip" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="display">
        <p:dataList value="#{checkboxView.selectedConsoles}" var="console">
            #{console}
        </p:dataList>
        <p:dataList value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities}" var="city">
            #{city}
        </p:dataList>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
 </h:form>
</h:body>
 </html>
```

My bean

```
package Bean;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

  @ManagedBean
  public class CheckboxView {

   private String[] selectedConsoles; 
   private String[] selectedCities;  
   private List<String> cities;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    cities.add("San Francisco");
    cities.add("London");
    cities.add("Paris");
    cities.add("Istanbul");
    cities.add("Berlin");
    cities.add("Barcelona");
    cities.add("Rome");
    cities.add("Sao Paulo");
    cities.add("Amsterdam");
}

public String[] getSelectedConsoles() {
    return selectedConsoles;
}

public void setSelectedConsoles(String[] selectedConsoles) {
    this.selectedConsoles = selectedConsoles;
}

public String[] getSelectedCities() {
    return selectedCities;
}

   public void setSelectedCities(String[] selectedCities) {
    this.selectedCities = selectedCities;
 }

     public List<String> getCities() {


     return cities;

  }



  }



  the web.xml

 <context-param>  
 <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
 <param-value>south-street</param-value>  
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your web.xml file ?

it must have servlet definition and mapping for JSF.

Below elements must exists in your web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

please note that *.xhtml means that the Faces Servlet will handle all JSF files with extension .xhtml you have to change it to your defined extension.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... yes my web.xml have all this definitions.My project work so fine untill I want to use primfaces the h: an f: balise work but p: (which refer to primefaces) no

Comment: So it seems that your build path is not configured correctly unless it will be fine. try to make sure that Primefaces jar is added successfully to your build path if it's already configured try to manually add it in /Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib folder and refresh your application.

Comment: I have exactly this problem :  Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.orgx/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

Comment: You have to make sure that your build path include this jar plus you have to clean and build your project then try again.

Comment: unfortunatly I have done all what you suggest but I still have the same error...I gona losing mind with this :\ .. I have creat a new librairy in which I add the primefaces jar in my build path but I still have an underlining in this line of my xhtml page  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.orgx/ui">

Comment: Really this is very strange issue, I think you have to check your eclipse comparability with JSF, try to install Jboss JSF plugin in your eclipse and check again.

Comment: That s mean I will change glassfish server?..thank you so much for your help ..If you have alredy work with primefaces in eclipse ID and glassfish server please tell me what are the changes I must do(all step may be I have do somthing wrong)

Comment: no need to remove glassfish, it's working fine with me please try to install JBoss Tools from eclipse market place and try again, please make sure also you have set the JSF facets, go to your eclipse project properties >> Project Facets >> Java Server Faces

Comment: Yes I have set JSF facets (I just verify this)..Ok I will try to install JBoss tools..hope this method work .. thank you

Comment: yes it finally work thank you very very much @user3561005 for your support...the solution was stranger I user primefaces3 but I have to use this xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" not xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" ... realy thank you I was trying to execute your suggestion and I find this solution :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. latest primefaces version is 5.0 so you have to check it.

Comment: thank you A.Shaheen..Ok I will try it just if you permitin version 3 I have 2 jar..source and snapshot but in version 5 I find only sources one..can you explain to me what is the difference?

Comment: No you have to use the binary jar, you can download from here [link] http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/primefaces/primefaces/5.0/primefaces-5.0.jar, the source jar contains source code for primefaces if you want to manually change some core source code but you don't need that now, just use the jar from above link. Good luck

Comment: Really I don't know :)

Comment: Oh noo I try to change my jar (I delete primefaces3 jars and I put primefaces5.jar into my library)and then I have this error ... deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class. Please see server.log for more details.